# How to avoid losing receiver when sending notification?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

### How my programs works

I have backend with several objects, which have PropetyChanged event. When some property is changed, the notification is fired. On the frontend side I have GUI written in WPF, and several properties are binded directly to WPF widgets.

To make GUI responsive, all the computation is done in additional thread.

So, in general, classic WPF app.

### Error

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); // (*)
}
```

This code sends notifications, however it throws exception at (*) because PropertyChanged is null (yes, just **after** checking for null).

### Question

My guess is it is because of rebinding in WPF -- in my code I change the sender, so WPF has to unregister receiver and register it to the new sender. Exception is thrown rarely (I get one exception every ~40000 executions passes, each one is equivalent roughly to one change of the sender) but it **does** happen.

Now -- **how to properly lock PropertyChange, so I can check for null AND send the notification as an atomic operation?** I don't want to do this by trial & error, because I could find out side effects in every 1M-th execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pattern to solve this problem:

```
var evt = PropertyChanged;
if ( evt != null ) evt( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
```

Comment: Are you sure you copy values (receivers) and not just a reference of event?

Comment: This is the correct solution. It copies the delegate (which can be null). Your problem is that you're reading the field twice (first to check, the to call) which is a race condition.

Comment: Delegates are immutable, so once you have a reference to one, it can never change. If handlers are added or removed from an event, a new delegate instance is created.

Comment: @macias : you do not need to copy values, by introducing a new reference to object you preventing it from being GCed

Comment: @Nick Butler, this part I didn't find in any resource. Thank you for clarification, I am happy the solution is so simple, however it is also disturbing, then you normally see only the incorrect examples of sending notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the event wiring in event property declaration

```
private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
   add 
   { 
     // intercept here
     _propertyChanged += value; 
   }
   remove 
   { 
     // intercept here
     _propertyChanged -= value; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, wait, I'll take back my previous comment -- do you suggest, that I should add locks in changing receivers ("intercept here" part) and sending notifications, so only one action can be done at one time?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you can check when the event is registered/unregistered.

Comment: quoting you "how to properly lock PropertyChange, so I can **check for null** AND send the notification as an atomic operation?"

Comment: I don't follow you. The only thing I can think of is adding lock in those 3 places. As you said, you think of something else, so could you please add more code to your answer -- it can be pseudo-code. Thank you.

Comment: maybe my answer is misleagind, Nick has good point. I was just thinking about how to find out more about event un-/registering, i.e. the stack trace, etc. But it look that's it's not what you've been asking.